# How to allow only two (or more) users access to a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, users

I need to allow two specific users, not groups, to use a certain plugin that is listed in the admin menu area. I have this code which allows one user (user id = 2) to see the plugin :

```
add_menu_page( 'My Plugin Page', __('My Plugin Page', 'my-plugin-page'), 2, 'afp', 'mp_items_page', 'dashicons-admin-site', '101.1' );
```

I know I can use roles but that allows all users in that group to access the plugins page which is no good to me. One of the users I need to add is admin, the other is an author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new user role or set user access level, if you wanted for large group of user.

If not you just go with the normal way of adding the menu. But in printing the admin page just make sure that current user is what you are expecting to see the page.

EG:

```
    add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title,
                   $capability, $menu_slug, 'sample_function', $icon_url, $position );

    function sample_funtion(){
     $allowed_user_list = array(2,18);
     $current_user_ID = get_current_user_id();
    if(in_array($current_user_ID,$allowed_user_list)){
    //now print everything you want. Only allowed user will see it

    }

}
```

Comment: Cool. My Pleasure  :)